# Pip use local module installed with -e instead of from git

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I am trying to develop for 2 different Python 3 Modules and pip. In order to develop and test them  without rebuilding, I am using `pip install -e`. One module is dependent on another, and they are both NOT found on PyPI (git install only).

My current method of development is to `pip install -e Module2/.`, then remove `Module1` (since it is installed from git) with `pip uninstall Module1` and then reinstall with `pip install -e Module1/.`

How do I prevent one module from automatically installing from git instead of using the local module that is installed with the `-e` flag? Thank you!

My `setup.py` file:

```py
import setuptools
from setuptools import  find_packages

setuptools.setup(
    name="Module2",
    version="1.3",
    install_requires=[
        "Module1 @ git+[Module1_Git_Link].git",
        "numpy",
        "scipy",
        "pandas",
        "matplotlib"
    ],
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

My `requirements.txt` file:

```
Module1>=1.3.2
numpy
scipy
matplotlib
pandas
```

Edit 1: I don't want to use `dependency_links` because that has been deprecated/removed in recent versions of pip

Comment: @BradSolomon Outdated answers: `dependency_links` no longer work. The OP uses new syntax for `install_requires` which is the correct way.